# SQL query Taking long time to execute

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g, query-optimization

Im trying to execute the below query and it is taking long time to execute. Is there anyway i can make changes in the below query? It is taking more than 60mins for executing and sometimes it is getting hanged.

```
select distinct z.por_s as Portfolio_Number,z.lse_s as 
Account_Number,y.les_s as Lessee_Number,z.unit_S as Asset,to_char(x.d_com_s, 
'MM/DD/YYYY') as Start_Date, to_char(x.d_mat_s,'MM/DD/YYYY') as 
Maturity_Date, x.p_con_d as Yield,k.nam_long_s as Venodr_Name,z.dlr_s as 
Venodr_Number,y.client_s_name_s as Customer_Name,y.short_add_s as 
Billing_Address,y.short_cty_s as City,y.st_s as State,z.eq_add_s as 
Equipment_Address, x.trm_l as Original_Term,(x.TRM_L - x.PMT_L) as 
Remaining_Term,z.id_S as EquipmentSerialID,z.org_d as Original_Amount, 
(NVL(x.lsd_unit_d, 0.0) - NVL(x.acl_depr_d, 0.0) - NVL(x.sec_d, 0.0) - 
NVL(SUM(b.bal_d), 0.0) + NVL(SUM(NVL(a.pamt_b_d, 0.0) + NVL(a.iamt_b_d, 0.0) 
- NVL(a.pamt_p_d, 0.0) - NVL(a.iamt_p_d, 0.0)), 0.0) - NVL(x.op_bill_adj_d, 
0.0) + NVL(x.unrec_in_d, 0.0)) as OPR_Remaining_Net_Investment,
(NVL(x.rec_d, 0.0) + NVL(SUM(NVL(d.aamt_b_d, 0.0) - NVL(d.aamt_p_d, 0.0)), 
0.0) +  NVL(SUM(NVL(a.pamt_b_d, 0.0) + NVL(a.iamt_b_d, 0.0) - 
NVL(a.pamt_p_d, 0.0) - NVL(a.iamt_p_d, 0.0)), 0.0) + NVL(x.tot_res_d, 0.0) - 
NVL(x.res_guar_d, 0.0) - NVL(x.l_ue_d, 0.0) + NVL(x.r_ue_d, 0.0) + 
NVL(x.i_ue_d, 0.0) + NVL(x.d_ue_d, 0.0) + NVL(x.l_in_ptd_d, 0.0) + 
NVL(x.r_in_ptd_d, 0.0) + NVL(x.i_in_ptd_d, 0.0) + NVL(x.d_in_ptd_d, 0.0) - 
NVL(x.sec_d, 0.0) - NVL(SUM(b.bal_d), 0.0) - NVL(x.susp_l_acc_d, 0.0) + 
NVL(x.susp_r_acc_d, 0.0) + NVL(x.susp_d_acc_d, 0.0) + NVL(x.susp_i_acc_d, 
0.0)) as PRE_Remaining_Net_Investment
,z.res_d as Residual_Asset ,n.bus_phn_s as Business_Phone, n.hom_phn_s as 
Home_phone,o.field19_s as Credit_Guarantee, o.field20_s as 
Residual_Guarantee,m.add_s as Guarantor_Address,m.add2_s as 
Guarantor_Address2,m.cty_s as Guarantor_City,m.st_s as 
Guarantor_State,m.zip_s as Guarantor_Zip
from rgc c 
FULL join rls x on c.APP_LSE_S = x.LSE_S
FULL Join rar a on x.LSE_S = a.LSE_S
FULL Join rsu b on x.LSE_S = b.LSE_S
FULL Join rarb d on x.por_s = d.por_s
FULL join vrcx_les y on x.les_s = y.les_s
FULL join req z on x.LSE_S = z.LSE_S
FULL join rlr k on z.dlr_s = k.dlr_s
FULL join ral n on x.les_s = n.les_s
FULL join rug o on x.lse_s = o.lse_s
FULL JOIN RGR m ON c.CLIENT_ID_S = m.GRN_S 
where x.act_s in ('AACQ', 'AASM', 'AEXM', 'ANOR', 'ARBK', 'ARED', 'AREN', 
'AXFR') and x.d_mat_s > to_date ('07/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
and a.por_s = x.por_s
AND a.com_s = x.com_s
AND a.reg_s = x.reg_s
AND a.off_s = x.off_s
AND a.lse_s = x.lse_s
AND d.invo_s = a.invo_s
AND d.a_typ_s in ('PROR', 'IDR2', 'SECD')
AND NVL(a.income_accrued_c, ' ') <> 'N'
group by z.por_s,z.lse_s,y.les_s,z.unit_S,x.d_com_s,
x.d_mat_s,x.p_con_d,k.nam_long_s,
z.dlr_s,y.client_s_name_s,y.short_add_s,
y.short_cty_s,y.st_s,z.eq_add_s,x.trm_l,x.PMT_L,  
z.id_S,z.org_d,x.lsd_unit_d,x.acl_depr_d,x.sec_d,
b.bal_d,a.pamt_b_d,a.iamt_b_d,a.pamt_p_d,a.iamt_p_d,
x.op_bill_adj_d,x.unrec_in_d,x.rec_d,x.res_guar_d,
d.aamt_b_d,d.aamt_p_d,a.pamt_b_d,a.iamt_b_d,a.pamt_p_d,  
a.iamt_p_d,x.tot_res_d,x.res_guar_d,x.l_ue_d,x.r_ue_d,
x.i_ue_d,x.d_ue_d,x.l_in_ptd_d,x.r_in_ptd_d,x.i_in_ptd_d,
x.d_in_ptd_d,x.susp_l_acc_d,x.susp_r_acc_d,x.susp_d_acc_d,
x.susp_i_acc_d,z.res_d,n.bus_phn_s,n.hom_phn_s,o.field19_s,
o.field20_s,m.add_s,m.add2_s,m.cty_s,m.st_s,m.zip_s;
```

Any changes needs to made on this query just help me out on this.

Comment: You are doing FULL OUTER JOIN on eleven tables: why is that? You appear to have some join criteria in the WHERE clause, so probably those joins will produce the same result set as INNER JOINs. So maybe it doesn't make any difference. But a query which is expressive of intent is easier to understand and diagnose.

Comment: Beyond that, we have to ask the usual query tuning questions. How many rows in each table? What percentage of the rows will be returned? Which columns are indexed? Is the data distribution skewed? How fresh are the table stats? At the very least you should post an Explain Plan

Comment: first thing is to run an explain plan.

Comment: Or even better, a SQL Monitor report.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select distinct z.por_s as Portfolio_Number,
    z.lse_s as Account_Number,
    ...

    from rgc c 
    FULL join rls x on c.APP_LSE_S = x.LSE_S #match nro account (1)
    FULL Join rar a on x.LSE_S = a.LSE_S #match nro account (2)
    FULL Join rsu b on x.LSE_S = b.LSE_S #match nro account (3)
    FULL Join rarb d     on x.por_s = d.por_s  #match (4)
    FULL join vrcx_les y on x.les_s = y.les_s #match nro less
    FULL join req z      on x.LSE_S = z.LSE_S #match nro account

    FULL join rlr k on z.dlr_s = k.dlr_s

    FULL join ral n on x.les_s = n.les_s #match nro less
    FULL join rug o on x.lse_s = o.lse_s #match nro account

    FULL JOIN RGR m ON c.CLIENT_ID_S = m.GRN_S 
    where x.act_s in 
    ('AACQ', 'AASM', 'AEXM', 'ANOR', 'ARBK', 'ARED', 'AREN', 'AXFR')  #use this in the full join (2)
    and x.d_mat_s > to_date ('07/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') #use this in the full join (2)
    and a.por_s = x.por_s #use this in the full join (2)
    AND a.com_s = x.com_s #use this in the full join (2)
    AND a.reg_s = x.reg_s #use this in the full join (2)
    AND a.off_s = x.off_s  #use this in the full join (2)
    AND a.lse_s = x.lse_s #use this in the full join (2)
    AND d.invo_s = a.invo_s  #use this in the full join (4)
    AND d.a_typ_s in ('PROR', 'IDR2', 'SECD')
    AND NVL(a.income_accrued_c, ' ') <> 'N' #nvl is not necesary
    group by z.por_s,z.lse_s,y.les_s,z.unit_S,x.d_com_s,
    ...
```

I would put the restrictions in the joins, so you dont combine all the rows (1000 x 1000 for example), just the rows you need (100 x 1000) Like this:

```
 from rgc c 
    FULL join rls x on c.APP_LSE_S = x.LSE_S #match nro account (1)
    FULL Join rar a on x.LSE_S = a.LSE_S #match nro account (2)
    and x.act_s in 
    ('AACQ', 'AASM', 'AEXM', 'ANOR', 'ARBK', 'ARED', 'AREN', 'AXFR')  #use this in the full join (2)
    and x.d_mat_s > to_date ('07/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') #use this in the full join (2)
    and a.por_s = x.por_s #use this in the full join (2)
    AND a.com_s = x.com_s #use this in the full join (2)
    AND a.reg_s = x.reg_s #use this in the full join (2)
    AND a.off_s = x.off_s  #use this in the full join (2)
    AND a.lse_s = x.lse_s #use this in the full join (2)
    AND a.income_accrued_c <> 'N' #nvl is not necesary, if its null its <> from 'N'

    FULL Join rsu b on x.LSE_S = b.LSE_S #match nro account (3)
    FULL Join rarb d     on x.por_s = d.por_s  #match (4)
     and d.invo_s = a.invo_s  #use this in the full join (4)
     AND d.a_typ_s in ('PROR', 'IDR2', 'SECD')
    FULL join vrcx_les y on x.les_s = y.les_s #match nro less
    FULL join req z      on x.LSE_S = z.LSE_S #match nro account

    FULL join rlr k on z.dlr_s = k.dlr_s

    FULL join ral n on x.les_s = n.les_s #match nro less
    FULL join rug o on x.lse_s = o.lse_s #match nro account

    FULL JOIN RGR m ON c.CLIENT_ID_S = m.GRN_S 
 where 1=1
 group by ....
```

And I agree with the comments, if you want a more helpful answer, you have to post a description of every table used in the query as and a brief explanation of the fields in them. Also the functional explanation of the query, what kind of information you want to extract.